# Derivative of this complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers, wolfram-alpha

Assume that I have the following complex function

$$f(Z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\left(-0.5a(Z-1)\ln \left( \frac{Z-1}{Z+1} \right) +0.5b(Z+1)\ln \left( \frac{Z-1}{Z+1} \right) \right)$$

where $Z$ is some complex variable, $i$ is $\sqrt{-1}$, and $a$ and $b$ are real constants. It is my goal to find the derivative of $f$ with regards to $Z$, i.e.

$$f'(Z) = \frac{df(Z)}{dZ}=?$$

Since I am not very familiar with complex differentiation, I tried evaluating this in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20of%201%2F%282*pi*i%29*%28-a*0.5*%28z-1%29*log%28%28z-1%29%2F%28z%2B1%29%29%2Bb*0.5*%28z%2B1%29*log%28%28z-1%29%2F%28z%2B1%29%29%29%20%20%20%20wrt%20z). You can check the result by clicking the link or entering the following query yourself:

```
derivative of 1/(2*pi*i)*(-a*0.5*(z-1)*log((z-1)/(z+1))+b*0.5*(z+1)*log((z-1)/(z+1))) wrt z
```

Curiously, the solution Wolfram Alpha returns contains a lot of decimal numbers, as if use was made of some kind of approximation of expansion. Unfortunately, don't have a Wolfram Alpha Pro account, so I cannot check the intermediate steps myself. [Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/) comes up with a similar solution but also skips the critical steps.

Do you know what exactly is going on here? Was there an expansion or approximation used, and if so, where and why?

Comment: For some reason, WA converted $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ into a decimal approximation. If you remove the $\frac{1}{2\pi i}$ factor from the WA input, things look more natural. Then just multiply the result with $\frac{1}{2\pi i}$.

Comment: Aaaah, yes, that explains it! So fortunately everything is a lot simpler than it looks like. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Replace $0.5$ by $\frac 12$ and it works